# What is the best way to capture output form scilab into a publishable format?

Tags: scilab

I am using scilab to do some simple simulation. The outcome will a number of plot and graph. What is the easiest way to capture these outputs and publish them into a pdf or ps file?

Hopefully it is simple to do that I can include the boilerplate code into my scilab script itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **xs2ps**, **xs2eps** or **xs2pdf**. For example:

```
scf(0);
x=0:0.01:10;
for i=1:5
  y=sin(i*x);
  plot2d(x,y);
  filename=sprintf('d:\foo_%d.ps',i);
  xs2ps(0,filename);
  clf();
end
```